# Multiple users on host with ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

Is there a way to loop through a list of users and execute a role on a target as that given user?

Something like:

```
- name: Run profile installation
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: "{{ item }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Include the installProfile role
      include_role:
        name: installProfile
  loop:
    - myuser
    - anotheruser
```

When I run this I get an error:

`ERROR! 'loop' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

Any ideas? I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. Basically, I want to run the same play for multiple users across the given hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below. However, we don't know how many users are in the list and you would need to create a task  for each user and host, then add a condition.

Example of playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users:
        - myuser
        - anotheruser
  tasks:
    - name: Execute role as specific user
      include_role:
        name: installProfile
        apply:
          become: true
          become_method: sudo
          become_user: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

The other option I can think of is to define each user for each host instead of looping. Ansible already does that for you.

```
[mytargets]
host1 ansible_user=user1
host2 ansible_user=user2
```

Comment: This appears to work:

`- name: Install dotfiles for user accounts
  hosts: was
  gather_facts: true
  remote_user: "{{ item }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Include the installProfile role
      include_role:
        name: installProfile
      loop:
        - pvansibleadmin
        - wasadm
        - ihsadm

Comment: If you are basically targeting your hosts and use all the users in the list, then the task I provided should work. You just need to exclude the condition.

Comment: Getting this with that block:

ERROR! 'remote_user' is not a valid attribute for a IncludeRole

The error appears to be in '/home/username/workspace/ansible/distributeProfile/site.yml': line 43, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - name: Execute role as specific user
      ^ here

Comment: I cannot change my answer: Can you add `vars:` and indent `become`, `become_method` and `remote_user` under it.

Comment: this is syntactically correct, but doesnt actually "become":

- name: Install dotfiles for user accounts
  hosts: was
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Include the installProfile role
      include_role:
        name: installProfile
        apply:
          become: true
          become_user: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - userA
        - userB

Comment: Ok, reworked a little bit:

`
- name: Install dotfiles
  hosts: was
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users:
        - pvansibleadmin
        - wasadm
  tasks:
    - name: Execute role as specific user
      include_role:
        name: installProfile
        apply:
          become: true
          become_method: sudo
          remote_user: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
`

But I'm getting a message about missing sudo password - I set up the account for passwordless sudo, is there something I need to configure so it doesn't ask?

Comment: instead of vars add `apply:` inside include_role, at the same level as name and indent `become`, `become_method` and `remote_user` under apply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252028/discussion-between-ayuuk-jaay-and-kevin-huntly).